# Prove $e^{b\log(a)}$ is single valued if, and only if $b$ is an integer.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We difine $\log (z) = \ln|z|+i \arg(z)$ where $|z|$ stands for the real logarithm of $|z|$ and $\arg (z) = \arg (z) + 2k \pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

**Problem** Prove $e^{b \log(a)}$ is single-valued if, and only if $b$ is an
integer. What can you say if $b$ is rational?

One of the properties of the logarithm is $z^a = e^{a \log(z)}$, where $\log(z^{a}) = a\log(z)$.

Then, if $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$ we have $a^b=e^{b \log(a)}$ and $b \log(a)=b \ln|a|+ i\arg(b)=\ln(|a|^b)+i \arg(a)$ so
$$a^b=|a|^b e^{i\arg(a)} = |a|^b (\cos(a)+i\sin (a))$$ Then $\cos(a)+i\sin(a)= \pm 1$ implies $a=n \pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

But I don't see how to relate $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ or with rational. Could you help me? please

Comment: "One of the properties of the **real** logarithm is $z^a = \mathrm{e}^{a \ln z}$ ..."  Why do you think you should be applying this in the context of the complex logarithm?

Comment: Is the only propertie that I know of log that is relate to the exponencial. Other propierties is log($z_{1}*z_{2}$)=log($z_{1}$) + log($z_{2}$) and log($\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}}$)$=$ log($z_{1}$) $-$ log ($z_{2}$) where $z_{1},z_{2} \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

We are literally told that the symbols "$\log(a)$" denote $\ln |a| + \mathrm{i} (\mathrm{Arg}(a) + 2 \pi k)$, for $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.  So, \begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{b \log(a)} &= \mathrm{e}^{b \left( \ln |a| + \mathrm{i} (\mathrm{Arg}(a) + 2 \pi k) \right)}, k \in \Bbb{Z}  \\
    &= \mathrm{e}^{b \ln |a| + \mathrm{i}\, b \mathrm{Arg}(a) + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} \,b k}, k \in \Bbb{Z}  \\
    &= \mathrm{e}^{b \ln |a| + \mathrm{i}\, b \mathrm{Arg}(a)} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} \,b k}, k \in \Bbb{Z}
  \text{.}
\end{align*}
The first factor in the final line is constant.  The second factor gives a set of values as $k$ varies.  That set contains $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}\,b \cdot0} = 1$.  The exponential is single-valued if that is the only element of that set.  If $b \in \Bbb{Z}$, then $bk \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} bk} = 1$.  Alternatively, if $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i} b k} = 1$, $2\pi \mathrm{i} \,b k$ is an integral multiple of $2 \pi \mathrm{i}$, so $bk \in \Bbb{Z}$ for all $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.  Since $b \cdot 1 \in \Bbb{Z}$ (when $k = 1$), this forces $b \in \Bbb{Z}$.

If $b = \frac{p}{q} \in \Bbb{Q}$, with $q > 0$ and $\gcd(p,q) = 1$, then $\left\{ 2\pi\mathrm{i} \, bk : k \in \Bbb{Z} \right\}$ has $q$ elements, the $q^\text{th}$ roots of $1$.  So $\mathrm{e}^{b \log(a)}$ has $q$ values, differing only by which root of unity is chosen from this set.